# Script using trap and wait shows inconsistent behaviour across different systems

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, scripting, fedora

The following script shows inconsistent behaviour across different systems (Fedora, CentOS & RHEL) I've ran it on:

```
#!/bin/sh -p

set -x

SCRIPT=`basename $0`

case "$1" in 
   start) 
      ./$SCRIPT start_internal &
      ;;
   start_internal)
      eval "nohup sleep 5 > test.log 2>&1 &"
      pid=$!

      echo "PROC is started (with pid $pid)..."

      # Trap signals 9 and 15 and pass on to child process
      trap 'kill $pid' 2 3 15
      wait $!
      echo "I'm done!"
      exit 0
      ;;
esac

exit 0
```

It's a test script I've extracted from a much larger init.d script which I'm supposed to debug. It is thus usually run using `scriptname start` either manually or some init system.

**Behaviour one**

On my Centos 7.3 and Fedora 25 systems the script exits immediately and shows the following output:

```
$ ./test.sh start
++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ ./test.sh start
++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ exit 0
+ ./test.sh start_internal
+ exit 0
++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ eval 'nohup sleep 5 > test.log 2>&1 &'
+ pid=25969
+ echo 'PROC is started (with pid 25969)...'
PROC is started (with pid 25969)...
+ trap 'kill $pid' 2 3 15
+ wait 25969
++ nohup sleep 5
$
```

Then after the sleep has expired the console prints out the following:

```
+ echo 'I'\''m done!'
I'm done!
+ exit 0
$
```

**Behaviour two**

On two other systems running Centos 6.8 and RHEL 7.2 it just hangs after the line `++ nohup sleep 5` and waits for the sleep to expire or the user press the enter key.

```
$ ./test.sh start
++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ ./test.sh start
++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ exit 0
+ ./test.sh start_internal
+ exit 0
$ ++ basename ./test.sh
+ SCRIPT=test.sh
+ case "$1" in
+ eval 'nohup sleep 5 > test.log 2>&1 &'
+ pid=7304
+ echo 'PROC is started (with pid 7304)...'
++ nohup sleep 5
PROC is started (with pid 7304)...
+ trap 'kill $pid' 2 3 15
+ wait 7304
```

I believe that behaviour one is the intended one while behaviour two is a bug related to a difference in the OS which I am now supposed to find.

Any ideas where I should start investigating?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is typically a link to a shell binary,   have you checked that you are using the same shell and shell version on all OSes

Comment: `/bin/sh`points to `/bin/bash` on all systems, the bash versions range from 4.1 to 4.3